# lunch command not displaying hiKey as target even after installing

Tags: android, android-source

I have a directory to which the android source tree is downloaded from the repo.
Now i have downloaded "https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/linaro-hikey-20160226-67c37b1a.tgz" and placed this under source directory and ran the following command

$ tar xzf linaro-hikey-20160226-67c37b1a.tgz

$ ./extract-linaro-hikey.sh

When i try to build against HiKey target, using the following command
 . ./build/envsetup.sh
 and then
 lunch

It is not listing the Hikey as a target. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linaro Hikey was not yet added to a release branch in AOSP. I presume you picked a release branch such as `android_6.0.1_r9`. repo sync the `master` branch. and it should appear as a lunch option.

The commit where the device dir for hikey was added is: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+/39e102a459e4b0accd5fbe6df64c9253d3f9616c